# Sentinel 2 surface reflectance error Python code Google Earth Engine

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, atmospheric-correction

We are trying to do the surface reflectance correction using Python codes in Spyder. The study area is defined as a polygon geometry and it's a fairly large area. We want to get all sentinel images that covered the study area in 2017 and correct all of them.

However when we run the python code, error popped up saying there is too many pixels in our study area:

```
EEException: Error in map(ID=20170103T172712_20170103T173023_T13QGE):
Image.reduceRegion: Too many pixels in the region. Found 220713615, but only 10000000 allowed.
```

We tested - the pixel number 220713615 should be the pixels of the geometry we specified (the study area). We tried a smaller geometry with less than 10000000 pixels, and the code worked perfectly.

Weird things are: we are not using any "Image.reduceRegion" function in our code, and it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the pixels of the study area if we want to surface correct the satellite images.

Comment: For coding questions please always include a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, the max pixel's allowed is 10000000. You can change this to suit your data:

```
image.reduceRegion({
  reducer: x,
  geometry: x,
  scale: x,
  maxPixels: 1e9
});
```